# How to refresh Container in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a page coded in Flutter that builds a Container upon data read from api.
I would like to refresh this Container once a checkbox is tapped. I use saveStatus(...) function for this.
At some point within this function - after database is updated - I would like to refresh its contents.

Of course I am able to re navigate to this page, but this reloads all components that takes time and looks bad.

I have seen many similar posts but none of solutions I tried worked for me.

Could you please advice on how to do this?

```
class ListDetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListDetailsPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<ListDetailsPage> createState() => _ListDetailsPageState();
}


class _ListDetailsPageState extends State<ListDetailsPage> {


  Future<List<PostListDetails>> postsFuture = getPosts();

  static Future<List<PostListDetails>> getPosts() async {

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    ...
    
    Response response = await post(Uri.parse('https://somehost.com/api.php'),
      headers: <String, String>{
      ....
      },
      ....
    );

    if(response.statusCode == 200){
    ....
    }else {
        ....
    }

    final List body = json.decode(response.body);
    return body.map((e) => PostListDetails.fromJson(e)).toList();


  }


  void saveStatus(String nazwa, int status) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final token = ...;
    final listID = ...;

    try{
      Response response = await post(Uri.parse('https://somehost.com/api.php'),
        headers: <String, String>{
        ...
        },
        body: <String, String>{
        ...
        },
      );

      if(response.statusCode == 200){

        // ---> TODO refresh Lists here



      }else {
    ...
      }
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<PostListDetails>>(
          future: postsFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final posts = snapshot.data!;
              return buildPosts(posts);
            } else {
              return const Text("No data...");
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget buildPosts(List<PostListDetails> posts) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('XXXXXXX'),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: signUserOut,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: posts.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final post = posts[index];
            return Container(
            ...
            Checkbox(
                                  value: Int2Bool(post.status!.toInt()),
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    setState(() {post.status = Bool2Int(value!);});
                                    saveStatus(post.nazwa!, post.status!);
                                  },
                                )
            ...
            )
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to refresh the UI, you can reassign the future variable`postsFuture`  and call setState.

```dart
saveStatus(...){
  .....
  setState((){
    postsFuture = getPosts();
  });
}
```

---

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('XXXXXXX'),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: signUserOut,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
            )
          ],
        ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<PostListDetails>>(
          future: postsFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final posts = snapshot.data!;
              return buildPosts(posts);
            } else {
              return const Text("No data...");
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

 Widget buildPosts(List<PostListDetails> posts) {
   return ListView.builder(...);
 }
```

Comment: OK... it looks it works the same way that navigating the page again... I mean that entire widget is rebuilt. What I would like to do is just rebuilding the component part or body...

Comment: You can use Futurebuilder on body

Comment: I'm a beginner in flutter and do not understand - sorry for that. Could you please explain more on this? Thanks :)

Comment: Try to shift  appBar from  `buildPosts` to `build` method. And  no need to have a second scaffold.  return the ListView form  `buildPosts`.

Comment: OK... it works in better way, but still has some delays... I will need to work on this more... anyway THANKS for helping :)